# thymeleaf double brackets converter doesn't show all property of entity

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a problem with using converter in my code

I'm using mongodb with spring 
when I use single brackets with entity "${institute}"  thymeleaf return object without conversion as well as below

```
{"id":{"timestamp":1550247179,"machineIdentifier":3569655,"processIdentifier":2292,"counter":9075706,"timeSecond":1550247179,"date":"2019-02-15T19:42:59.000+03:30","time":1550247179000},"instituteName":"werwe","establishedDate":"2018-04-22T00:00:00.000+04:30","activityType":"","address":"","contactNumber":"","website":"","products":[""]}
```

but when I use double brackets with entity "${{institute}}" thymeleaf just show me converted objectID as below

```
"5c66e50b3677f708f48a7bfa"
```

I want to show all converted property in output but thymeleaf just show me objectID. 
how can I show all converted properties like below?

```
{"id":"5c66e50b3677f708f48a7bfa","instituteName":"werwe","establishedDate":"2018-04-22T00:00:00.000+04:30","activityType":"","address":"","contactNumber":"","website":"","products":[""]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf double-brace syntax simply converts the value to a string with the registered **Conversion Service** as explained in detail in this [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#data-conversion-formatting). If you did not register a custom Conversion Service then the default `StandardConversionService` class simply executes `toString()` method of the object.

So if your object is a custom type then you can implement custom `toString()` method for your specific needs. Another way is to develop a class that implements `IStandardConversionService` and write your custom conversion logic. Please take a look at this [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conversion-services).